# UPDATE - SELECT - MYSQL #1093 - You can't specify target table 'temp1' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, database

I can't find solution to correct this big query, I always receive an error from database.

I have tre tables and I need to make changes on some attribute on some condition:

```
UPDATE o36t_orders as temp1,
  mytable as temp2
SET
  temp1.bonifico = 1,
  temp2.ultimo = 1
WHERE
  temp1.id_order IN (
    SELECT
      id_order
    FROM o36t_orders
    LEFT JOIN o36t_address ON (o36t_address.id_address = o36t_orders.id_address_delivery)
    LEFT JOIN mytable ON (
        mytable.Causale = CONCAT(
          o36t_address.lastname,
          ' ',
          o36t_address.firstname
        )
      )
    WHERE
      o36t_orders.bonifico <> 1
  )
  AND temp2.id IN (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM o36t_orders
    LEFT JOIN o36t_address ON (o36t_address.id_address = o36t_orders.id_address_delivery)
    LEFT JOIN mytable ON (
        mytable.Causale = CONCAT(
          o36t_address.lastname,
          ' ',
          o36t_address.firstname
        )
      )
    WHERE
      o36t_orders.bonifico <> 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the subqueries of the 2 IN clauses are identical (except the retuned column), I think that you can do what you want by a straight inner join of the 2 tables and that subquery (returning both columns):

```
UPDATE o36t_orders temp1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      id, id_order
    FROM o36t_orders
    LEFT JOIN o36t_address ON (o36t_address.id_address = o36t_orders.id_address_delivery)
    LEFT JOIN mytable ON (
        mytable.Causale = CONCAT(
          o36t_address.lastname,
          ' ',
          o36t_address.firstname
        )
      )
    WHERE
      o36t_orders.bonifico <> 1
) t ON t.id_order = temp1.id_order
INNER JOIN mytable temp2 ON temp2.id = t.id
SET
  temp1.bonifico = 1,
  temp2.ultimo = 1
```

Comment: I ask, only because I don't know, t what is it. ? Is it a way to call mytable , and then give another short name to mytable as temp2 so to make it possible all these operations ?

Comment: t is the alias of the subquery. It is needed so you can refer to its columns whuch you use for the joins.